# Sim not being accepted by tablet

Tags: tablet

I've recently bought an HCl ME Y2 tablet. However, it's not recognising my sim. Even after inserting the sim, it says, "**Mobile network unavailable**." I've tried changing the settings. But, in vain.
Is the tab faulty? Do I need to get it replaced? Or am I unaware of any setting in the tab?

Comment: **Mobile n/w unavailable** means that the tablet is accessing SIM card but there are no available n/ws in your area. Please select network manually in **Mobile Networks**.

Comment: I have a Vodafone sim. On tapping **Search available networks**, they are not giving the **Vodafone** option.

Comment: So you're not in a coverage area. Get a new network with better coverage area.

Comment: To make the first comment more precise: No networks *supported by the device*. It might as well be a SIM lock causing this, i.e. the device is locked to a specific provider *other than* the one of your insterted SIM. Check: Is there any network listed in the manual selection? Is another device of yours (or of a friend) listing available networks when in the same location (if that also fails, it's probably the "coverage" from MANIs last comment)?